# Difference of using quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

sorry for novice question.

What is the difference, are thay same or different?

```
$scope.someVar = {first: true} 
$scope.someVar = {'first': true}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript there is no difference, except in cases where the property name is a JS keyword or contains special characters (eg symbols, spaces, etc), or would otherwise be invalid as a variable name (eg starting with a digit), in which case the quotes are necessary to avoid a syntax error.

One reason for this confusion is JSON -- In JSON strings, the quotes *are* mandatory. I know you're not writing JSON in the code in the question, but this difference between JSON and JS does catch people out, particularly because a lot of people think of JSON as being the same as Javascript; they're not (quite) the same.

Comment: Note: JSON requires *double* quotes.

Comment: @bfavaretto - yes indeed, thanks for adding that; it's a good point I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 2):

They're the same. The second one is necessary when the key contains a reserved keywords, or spaces, like

```
{ 'some-id+with/special:chara cters': true}
```

Comment: reserved keyword and even keys having spaces!

Comment: yes, indeed. Everything that is not a valid identifier or, IIRC, an number literal. See http://mothereff.in/js-properties